# Using React Router v4 is it possible to create multi level routes in child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm fairly new to the React framework, and I have decided to use Router v4, even though it is in beta, at the time of writing this, it seems to be the best way to go about things.

I have a router that shows one of two components

```
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Category from './category/Category';
import Hist from './hist/Hist';

const Controls = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route path='/category/:categoryId' component={Category}} />
          <Route path='/Hist' component={Hist} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});

export default Controls;
```

This works like a charm, of course, what I want to do now is to have some more routing inside of the Category component. I have tried something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Category = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/category/1'>Category 1</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/category/2'>Category 2</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className='category-display'>
          <Route path='/category/1'>This is Category 1</Route>
          <Route path='/category/2'>This is Category 2</Route>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But this is giving me a weird error saying something like

```
Uncaught Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

Is it even possible to pull off a stunt like this or does anyone have any other good suggestions for me?

Or is the best solution to rethink and implement some sort of conditional rendering depending on the route I get to the Category component as props from the first router.

---

Update:

I realised that `<Route>` does not seem to accept contents, so I added a component called Display and imported it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Display

const Category = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to='/category/1'>Category 1</Link></li>
          <li><Link to='/category/2'>Category 2</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className='category-display'>
          <Route path='/category/1' component={Display} />
          <Route path='/category/2' component={Display} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

However Display is not rendered. Any ideas as to why this is would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turns out Router does not accept any contents, so I implemented a component to go in it like it is done in the Controls component. 

Still not working 100%, nothing seems to be rendered, I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it actually turns out that my update (see question above) did the trick. The Display component was at fault here, not the router.

So to recap if anyone else stumbles upon this:

`<Route>` does not accept any contents, one could have used the `render` function of `<Route>` to do some quick testing. Everything is neatly summarised in the [React Router API documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route).

Cheers!